# Firebase Cloud Functions - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined" while making Telegram Bot

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, telegram-bot

Hello I am developing a Telegram bot using Firebase cloud functions [Typescript]

My bot runs everything fine, it does it's job but something keeps my cloud functions always active and that's an error as the title states. I don't know how it's even happening because it's still keeps occurring continuously even after the function is finished and done it's job successfully.

This is what keeps my cloud function logs filled and it keeps increasing my function invocation count.

[image: Error]

The same thing keeps repeating on and on and on...

Here is my code by the way which basically gets the command from user and splits it in 2 part if the command has 2 words.

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {

  const isTelegramMessage = req.body
                          && req.body.message
                          && req.body.message.chat
                          && req.body.message.chat.id
                          && req.body.message.from
                          && req.body.message.from.first_name

  if (isTelegramMessage) {
    const chat_id = req.body.message.chat.id //Telegram User UID   
    const first_name = req.body.message.from.first_name //Telegram User First Name 
    const userInput = JSON.stringify(req.body.message.text)
    //const userTelegramUID = req.body.message.text.id

    if (userInput !== null) {

      const userCommand: string = userInput
      const userCommandSliced: string = userCommand.slice(1, -1)
      const userCommandSlicedLength: number = userCommandSliced.length
      console.log(`User command to split is: ${userCommandSliced} and length ${userCommandSlicedLength}`)

      const finalNumberOfWords: number = userCommand.split(' ').length
      console.log(`Number of words in string = ${finalNumberOfWords}`)

      let returnText: string

      if (finalNumberOfWords === 1) {
        //returnText = userCommand
        if (userCommandSliced === '/start') {
          console.log(`Start function used by ${chat_id}`)
          return res.status(200).send({ 
          method: 'sendMessage',
          chat_id,
          text: `Hello **${first_name}**` 
          }) 
        }
        else{
          console.log(`1 word sent by ${chat_id}`)
          returnText = userCommandSliced
          return res.status(200).send({ 
          method: 'sendMessage',
          chat_id,
          text: `Hello ${first_name}, response to  ${returnText} and this contains ${finalNumberOfWords} words.`
          })
        }
      }
      else if (finalNumberOfWords === 2) {
        let command_array:string[];
        command_array= userCommandSliced.split(" ", 2)

        const commandFn: string = command_array[0]      
        const commandArg: string = command_array[1]

        console.log(`${command_array} is the command array `)
        console.log(`${commandFn} is command function.`)
        console.log(`${commandArg} is argument.`)

        if (commandFn === '/fetch') { 
          //let usernameFetched: string;
          returnText = `${commandFn} used with ${commandArg}`

          let usernameFetched: string
              const snapshot = await admin.database().ref(`/Users/${commandArg}/username`).once("value")
              usernameFetched = snapshot.val()
              console.log(`${usernameFetched} is requested username.`)

              return res.status(200).send({ 
              method: 'sendMessage',
              chat_id,
              text: `Your username is ${usernameFetched}. \n\nCommand used was ${returnText}` 
              })
        }
        console.log(`2 words sent by ${chat_id}`)
      }
      else{
        return res.status(200).send({ 
        method: 'sendMessage',
        chat_id,
        text: `Please don't spam with ${finalNumberOfWords} words in the bot chat.` 
        })
      }
    }
    else{
      return res.status(200).send({ 
      method: 'sendMessage',
      chat_id,
      text: `Null message detected.` 
      })
    }
  }

  return res.status(200).send({ status: 'not a telegram message' })
})

export const router = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

**EDIT:** Here my function ends successfully but still it occurs. And more importantly these occur even if I don't send any telegram message [i.e don't invoke a function] it still occurs.

[image: Error]

And again my bot is working but the error is increasing my function invocations.

[image: bot working]

Function invocations since this issue has occured.

[image: Rise in invocations]

Comment: Probably you don't have a value in `req.body.message.text`. I mean it's `undefined` and `undefined !== null` is `true`.

Comment: @norbitrial I do have. See the variable `userInput`.  And as I said, the bot works perfectly. The only issue is the console logs and that error. Its increasing my function invocations as well. No its false. Because it's not `null`, rest of my functions are working fine and handling the Test excellently

Comment: Try changing the test from `null` to `undefined`. The error is saying the `userInput == undefined` which is what you want to test for, not `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because null is != 'undefined' in javascript.
So

Instead of

```
if (userInput !== null)
```

Use

```
if(typeof userInput !== 'undefined')
```